# Java concurrent - spurious wakeups and wait(timeout)

Tags: java, concurrency

I have learned that when waiting on an object, *the condition should be placed in a loop* instead of within a single `if condition`. One reason for that is to avoid various spurious wakeup calls that might occur.

For example:

```
synchronized (obj) {
    while (condition is false) {
        obj.wait(5 * 1000);
    }
    ... do something ...
}
```

However, I only want to wait 5 seconds for the thread to be notified. In the code above, the thread waits for 5 seconds. But after that period, if the condition is still false, we wait again. This would not be the case if I had the following:

```
synchronized (obj) {
    if (condition is false) {
        obj.wait(5 * 1000);
    }
    ... do something ...
}
```

But this contradicts the guideline we should use a loop instead of a single if condition!

How is this solved?

Comment: you may remember current time before entering the loop, and make condition true if given period elapsed on wakeup.

Comment: Doh, ofcourse. Good idea!

Comment: I answered my own question. Hopefully it is correct.

Comment: In the prose the condition only refers to the boolean under the assumption that it may wait indefinitely until it is notified. The timeout basically is a second condition.

Comment: @Dave nice, but I'd suggest [`ReentrantLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) and its `.tryAcquire(time, timeUnit)` for this. If you need just to block a current thread for a while, use `Thread.sleep()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's how i typically handle this:

```
long timeout = ....;
synchronized(obj) {
  long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
  while(!condition && (timeout > 0)) {
    obj.wait(timeout);
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    timeout -= (now - start);
    start = now;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, this might work:

```
synchronized (obj) {
    for (long time = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeout; !condition && System.currentTimeMillis() < time; ) {
        obj.wait(time - System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
    if (condition) {
        ... do something ...
    }
}
```